# validate email does not work cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, validation

```
Class Myprofile extends AppModel{
var $name ='Myprofile';
var $primaryKey = 'myprofileid';


 var $validate = array(
     'name'=> array(
         'rule'=>'notEmpty',
         'message'=>'Please Enter name'
     ),
     'email'=> array(
         'please enter your email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'notEmpty',
             'message'=>'please Enter your email'
         )
     ),
         'email does not correct format' => array(
             'rule'=>array('email','true'),
             'message'=>'email does not correct format'
         ),
         'email'=>array(
             'rule'=>'isUnique',
             'message'=>'the email already taken'
         )          
 );
```

the validate format email does not work 
i follow in book.cakephp.org but doesn't work
thank for any suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the "email" array too early as you can see in the reformatted code.